# Angular JS Animation ng repeat two collections

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to work out ng repeat animation when I add/remove items from two different arrays one after another but it doesn't seem to work really smoothly on chrome-it works on firefox. Here is the following example codes:

template.html

```html
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat='item1 in arr1' class="repeated-item">
      <span>{{ item1 }}</span>
     </li>
  </ul>
```

index.html

```html
<div>
      <div ng-include='template.html'></div>
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat='item2 in arr2' class="repeated-item">
            <span>{{  item2 }}</span>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

I notice animation works quite well for outside repeat except ng-included template. Hope you guys can help to figure out this.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the `<div ng-include='template.html'>` tag properly. Add the closing tag `</div>`.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say it is closed properly. I am not sure why when I add/remove from the two arrays one after another animation in ng-repeat inside ng-included template didn't work as outside one.